# Cron service fails to start

Tags: 14.04, server, scripts, cron, services

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to start cron service without success. I always get this after running `service cron start`:

Job for cron.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

`systemctl status cron.service` says that the cron service is loaded but failed:

```
cron.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cron; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-06-15 09:06:19 AWST; 6min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 22707 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cron start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 cron[22707]: Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
 cron[22707]: utility, e.g. service cron start
 cron[22707]: initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
 cron[22707]: Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
 cron[22707]: Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start cron
 cron[22707]: start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
 systemd[1]: cron.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
 systemd[1]: Failed to start cron.service.
 systemd[1]: cron.service: Unit entered failed state.
 systemd[1]: cron.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any hint on how to make cron service to successfully start?

Comment: 14.04 shipped with Upstart instead of systemd, so those systemd messages seem curious.

Answer (score 0):

If cron service is not active, failed or trying to restart, then killing it shouldnt be a problem. Follow the steps:

Kill it using:

> ```
> pkill -f crond
> ```

Start it using :

> ```
> systemctl start crond
> ```

Check crond status:

> ```
> systemctl status cron.service
> ```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered similar issue, and this is what I was seeing

```
 systemctl status crond.service
● crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-02-07 13:34:38 EST; 2min 37s ago
  Process: 31470 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/crond -n $CRONDARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 31470 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

What I did to resolve this by checking my cron log. I am running in rhel, and my log is at /var/log/cron, my issue was due to this 
...(CRON) DEATH (can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, other pid may be 31364): Resource temporarily unavailable

so I just did

```
pkill -f crond
```

then

```
systemctl start crond.service
```

then it's back to normal

```
systemctl status crond.service
● crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-02-07 13:37:19 EST; 1s ago
 Main PID: 31490 (crond)
   CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
           └─31490 /usr/sbin/crond -n
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to deal with the underlying issue. Just killing things is not a solution.